# Inserting a (jpg) picture into a cell in Microsoft Excel 2007

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, vba

Is it possible to insert a jpg image **inside** a cell, or do Excel cells only display alphanumeric characters (or references)?

Comment: This seems like something that could be done with VBA (apparently robihot agrees, having tagged the question with the `vba` tag). Does anyone know enough about VBA to know whether it is possible?

Comment: Answers to this question show how this can be done with VBA
http://superuser.com/questions/584650/how-do-i-load-external-images-into-excel

Answer (score 8):

There are two ways to insert image to the Excel cell.

First way is inserting image as the background of comments.

- Right-click on the cell
- Insert Comment
- Double-click on the border of the comment
- Choose the Colors and Lines tab
  -In the Fill section, click the drop-down for Color
- Choose Fill Effects... | Picture | Select Picture...
- Choose your picture and click Insert
- Click OK

the result will be like that

[image]

When you put mouse over the cell, it'll show the picture.

Another way what you can do is anchoring an image to the cell. You've to name the cell first. Right click on the cell, and "Define Name". then right click on the picture , add Hyperlink , choose "Place in this document", you'll see the name you'd set in the Defined Names, then Okay!
You'll find out like below.

[image]

You'll need to adjust the size of the image with the cell width/height.

Comment: mgpyone could you clarify where the image is when you right click on it please? Not sure how to select the image after the name definition.

Comment: Quick question, when you add image using `Fill Effects` (method 1), does it embed the image into Excel or keeps the path of the image? I am sending the excel with images in comment, do I need to send the images also?