# Insert an image into a excel comment

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

I follow the steps from [How do I load external images into Excel?](https://superuser.com/questions/584650/how-do-i-load-external-images-into-excel/584725#584725?newreg=a2f7c9182005404ea1d5354b34a76734)

but when inserting the function appears an error:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzgRR.png]

Any idea what is causing this error?

Comment: Can you please translate the error message to English? (Super User is an English-only site, and all the questions and answers must be in English.)

Comment: Sure.
Here it goes

"We found a problem on this formula. Try clicking Insert Function on the formulas tab to fix it, or click Help for more information about common problems with formulas. Not trying to write a formula? When the first character is the equal sign (=) or minus excel considers him a formula. When you type = 1 + 1 shows the cell 2. To avoid this insert apostrophe (') first"

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you need another level of indirection:
The second parameter of InsertCommentImage refers to a Cell Range, not a URL.
So if you put the URL in another cell, and that cell's address in the InsertCommentImage, it should work.