# Importing images into cells

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-excel, images

I have designed a PC program using Profound UI.  PUI presents IBM iSeries software to the user in a Windows format.  One program is for recording inventory of items that are moving from one location to another.  There is a grid -- table that includes various fields for description and one field for a jpg photo of the item.  One of the features of the program allows the user to export the grid to a csv file and then open in Excel (ver 7). Is there any way to populate the column where the pictures should appear with the .jpg images?  Right now, the .csv just diplays "0."

Many thanks for any response.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Inserting a (jpg) picture into a cell in Microsoft Excel 2007](http://superuser.com/questions/117623/inserting-a-jpg-picture-into-a-cell-in-microsoft-excel-2007)

Comment: @Scott I disagree, Teylyn's answer has hit the nail on the head. The question is more about what the csv file is capable of containing.

Comment: Karen, you should reword your question to avoid it being closed.

Comment: @Tog I have no problem with Teylyn's answer; I was just saying that this question has been asked before and already has an answer.  I believe that the canonical procedure is for the good answers to be copied to the earlier question.  But I guess I rushed to judgment; this question isn’t quite the same.  The title is a bit misleading.

Answer (score 4):

A jpg is a file. A CSV cannot contain files, it just contains text. If the images are linked to instead of embedded in your application, you may be able to add a column that contains the path and file name of the image. With that information in the CSV file, Excel can process it to construct a hyperlink or use a macro to insert the images into the Excel file, like in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/584650/how-do-i-load-external-images-into-excel/584698)