# Excel - Filling images using a reference image

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a spreadsheet that I use to create baseball cards for a tabletop baseball game.  There are about 20 cards on my sheet, and I'd like to add a spot where I can set the logo and have it reflect that logo in each card without having to update 20 different images each time I create cards for a new team (and thus, a new logo).  Is there a way to automate this process similar to setting one cell equal to the value of another (=A4, for instance)?

I think the images aren't part of a cell and they float on top of the sheet, but I had hoped there was a way either with a macro or other VBA function (or maybe something built-in) that would accomplish this.

Comment: Did you try http://superuser.com/questions/584650/how-do-i-load-external-images-into-excel or http://superuser.com/questions/117623/inserting-a-jpg-picture-into-a-cell-in-microsoft-excel-2007

Comment: I didn't, but thanks, that looks like what I need.  I did some searching and found a lot of "how to insert an image into excel" but dismissed them because I already knew that process...seems like I shouldn't be judging a book by its cover.  I'll give this a whirl and mark the answer if it does what I need, thanks!